# Create specification in JPA having super class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity `Scan`, which have a field - super class `Metadata`. I would like to create a specification to find scans where

```
metadata.name = 'something'
```

Is it possible? When I try do it, I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [name] on this ManagedType  [Metadata].
```

The classes are listed below

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "scan")
public class Scan {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "scan_id")
    private Long id;

    // ... other fields

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Metadata metadata;

    // ... getters, setters

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "metadata")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "META_TYPE")
@Audited
public abstract class Metadata {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "metadata_id")
    private Long id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "metadata")
    @JoinColumn(name = "scan_id")
    private Scan scan;

    // ... getters, setters

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "letter_metadata")
@DiscriminatorValue("LETTER")
@Audited
public class LetterMetadata extends Metadata {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    // ... getters, setters

}
```

My repository class:

```java
@Repository
public interface ScanRepository extends JpaRepository<Scan, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Scan> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need such a query

```
select s from Scan s, LetterMetadata lmd 
where s.metadata.id=lmd.id where lmd.name=:lmdName
```

So the specification can be done this way

```
public static Specification<Scan> letterMetadataNameEquals(String lmdName) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        Root<LetterMetadata> lmd = query.from(LetterMetadata.class);
        
        return builder.equal(root.get("metadata").get("id"), lmd.get("id"))
               .and(builder.equal(lmd.get("name"), lmdName));
    }
}
```